# JavaScript: add image after name tied to id

Tags: javascript

A friend of mine passed me a ShoutBox for an upgrade. Some users who are DJs at the site's radio station want to show an [R] image after their name.

I can't figure out how to tie the image to an id.

Here is my code

```
var radios = document.getElementById("radios"); 
if(radios.innerHTML == 'yes') {
   radio = 'the image here';

  }
```

and here is how I display the username:

```
h = ' <a href="/userdetails.php?id=' + nps[a][1] + '" class="c' + nps[a][3] + ' " target="_blank">' + nps[a][2] + "</a> ";
```

The problem is if I add it like this:

```
h = ' <a href="/userdetails.php?id=' + nps[a][1] + '" class="c' + nps[a][3] + ' " target="_blank">' + nps[a][2] + "</a> " + radio;
```

it adds the image to everybody's name, instead of exclusively the radio DJ.

Could someone give me a hint of what I'm missing?

I really want to do this in JavaScript for practice.

Here is the php:

```
$id = 0 + $_SESSION['id'];
$r = mysql_query(" SELECT radios FROM users WHERE id = ".$id." ");
$radio = mysql_fetch_array($r);
echo  "<div id='radios'>" . $radio ['radios'] . "</div>";
```

Comment: thank you everybody for spareing time on my question i was abble to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var radios = document.getElementById("radios");` you really need to have a unique identifier per-user, is there anything that is unique per-user that you can use? Can you post an example.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the PHP code? This type of thing is probably better and easier to do in the PHP part. And then it will work even if the user has javascript turned off. But as far as I can see, when you define the variable radio, there is no way of telling what user it is looking for. Right now, it looks like you are looking in the same place regardless of which user it is.